# D3 with NPM not working properly

Tags: javascript, d3.js, npm

I have an angular project that I want to implement [D3.js](https://d3js.org/) into.

So in my terminal, I typed

> npm i d3

And started writing code

```
  buildGraph(){
    var x = scale.linear().domain([0, 5]).range([0, 5]);

    d3.select('.chart')
            .selectAll('div')
            .data(this.createdDataset)
            .enter().append('div')
            .style('width', function(d){ return x(d) + 'px'; })
            .text(function(d) { return d; });
  }
```

and imported in D3

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
```

But I'm receiving the following error message:

> program-quality.component.ts 32:16-24 "export 'scale' (imported as
>   'd3') was not found in 'd3'

So I tried importing scales like so

> npm i d3-scale

```
    import * as scale from 'd3-scale';
    var x = scale.linear().domain([0, 5]).range([0, 5]);
```

And I'm still getting the same error. I can see a d3-scales in my node_modules file. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the full code from the component where I'm trying to do this

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, AfterContentInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CalculationsService } from '../../services/calculations.service';
import { ProgramQualityCalculationsService } from '../../services/program-quality-calculations.service';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import * as scale from 'd3-scale';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-program-quality',
  templateUrl: './program-quality.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./program-quality.component.css']
})
export class ProgramQualityComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentInit{

  constructor(private _programQualityCalculations: ProgramQualityCalculationsService) { }

  AssessmentDiagnosticsBasline;
  DevelopmentBasline;
  PerformanceManagementBaseline;

  createdDataset: Array<number> = [];


  @Input() answers;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.AssessmentDiagnosticsBasline = this._programQualityCalculations.generateAssessmentDiagnosticsBaseline(this.answers);
    this.DevelopmentBasline = this._programQualityCalculations.generateDevelopmentBaseline(this.answers);
    this.PerformanceManagementBaseline = this._programQualityCalculations.generatePerformanceManagementBaseline(this.answers);
    this.createdDataset.push(this.AssessmentDiagnosticsBasline, this.DevelopmentBasline, this.PerformanceManagementBaseline);
    console.table(this.createdDataset);
  }

  ngAfterContentInit(){
    this.buildGraph();
  }

  buildGraph(){
    var x = scale.linear().domain([0, 5]).range([0, 5]);

    d3.select('.chart')
            .selectAll('div')
            .data(this.createdDataset)
            .enter().append('div')
            .style('width', function(d){ return x(d) + 'px'; })
            .text(function(d) { return d; });
  }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to install types/d3

npm install --save-dev @types/d3